# iOS Salesforce SDK Issue

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios

I have installed the iOS SDK by including it in my podfile. When I try to build the project the following error occurs:

[image]

My project is using the Standard Architectures (armv7, arm64) and I am already dependent on some third party libraries that use the same architectures. Is the most recent version of the SDK still reliant on a 32 bit architecture? Is there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out. In the podfile make sure you specify the latest version.

```
pod 'SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS', '~> 3.1.0'
```

I believe the 64 bit architecture wasn't supported until the 2.4 release.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the latest version is 3.2.0. And looks like we are missing the MobileCoreServices.framework in the pod spec. Try to add that framework if you are using 3.2.0 and see if that builds the project properly.

Comment: Just pushed the updated podspec. You can download the latest version 3.2.1 with the fix. Thanks for reporting the issue!